# Show progressBar until window.show()

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

I have problem with showing progress bar while window is loading.
Actually i have window with a lot of items in datagrid.
When im calling window.Show(), it tooks very long time till its open, so im wondering, if its possible to call something like:

```
 ShowProgressBar spb = new ShowProgressBar();
            spb.Topmost = true;
            spb.Owner = this.Owner;
            spb.Show();

            while(mainWin.isLoaded)
                  spb.updatePB(); // this method updating progressbar.value.
mainWindow.Show();
```

But it doesnt show progresbarr at all, while loading, only show when window is full-loaded.

Is there any helpful code? ;)

Comment: The while loop is inverted.
If you start off not loaded, it will skip the ui update and if you start off loaded it will keep trying to update the ui with "I am complete"

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that both of them are on the UI thread, so you won't be able to update the UI for the progress bar until you finish loading the MainWindow. The solution is to use another thread to update the ProgressBar's UI....

Something like this should work:

```
 Dispatcher progressDisptacher;
 var uiThread = new Thread(() =>
  {
      ShowProgressBar spb = new ShowProgressBar();
      spb.Topmost = true;
      spb.Show();
      progressDisptacher = spb.Dispatcher;

      // allowing the main UI thread to proceed 
     System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
   });
   uiThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
   uiThread.IsBackground = true;
   uiThread.Start();

   mainWindow.Show();
   progressDisptacher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Send);
```

As you can see, after the mainWindow loads, you can kill the progress bar thread using:
`progressDisptacher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Send);`

Comment: Although in theory this will work, it doesn't really address the actual root cause, which is that the OP is not treating the UI thread as the precious resource that it is and asynchronous running the IO systems.

Comment: Further more you will need to explain that you will need to update the ProgressBar using the new Dispatcher/Thread.
Although you could use INPC on a Progress property in the Model.

Comment: A "loading" screen is a very common request, and it addresses the root cause of blocking the UI thread by allowing another thread to show a waiting screen while the other one really loads. Since you do not know what he has is his form's initialization and if he *can* move things to be async, *your answer* doesn't help the OP solve his problem in any way... (But it *is* a very good explanation of the problem..!)

Comment: And about updating the progress bar, a simple animation can suffice  so he doesn't even need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged...

Comment: Ok, actually it works fine. Now problem with updating progressbar - i guess i cant update it while uiThread is alive, but how can i exactly do that? when im trying to do that as i wrote above, getting error that another proc own it

Comment: Can you post in your question the logic of the `spb.updatePB()` method?

Comment: Basically you'll want to use `this.Dispatcher.Invoke()` inside updatePB() if you get into problems post it in the question above...

Comment: Alternatively you could use a timer to wrap

    progressDisptacher.Invoke(() => spb.updatePB(), Priority);

Comment: Correct, you can choose to invoke only *part* of your method if you use invoke from *inside* updatePB or you can choose to invoke the *entire* method by using Aron's comment above.

Comment: Be careful with the timer before you shutdown the dispatcher. You have to dispose the timer to avoid trying to call a non-existent dispatcher.

Comment: As I said, we'll need to see the code to better understand what he's doing there

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to update the progress bar when your main window ISN'T loaded. So firstly you should want to invert the while loop.

However its a bit more subtle that single problem.

Welcome to the extremely painful work of STA threads. A quick rule of thumb is that anything that has to do with the what you see on the screen must be done with the main thread. And in fact a lot of what happens is when you aren't using the main thread, .net uses it to redraw anything that has changed (like the Progress bar).

To be able to show the progress bar you are going to have to return control of the UI thread back to what is called the message loop. The easiest way to do so is to return the method call. But before that you will want to setup a timer to periodically check the progress.

Your current code would just spend all day checking if the mainWindow is loaded, and not actually loading the mainWindow.

However the actual loading of the mainWindow is likely going to again need to use the main thread to construct.

Soooo...finally you should IsAsync out the binding that loads the items into the datagrid.

Comment: By that You mean i need to update progressBar when loading items in datagrid? But how about that, when i have also a lot of datagrids in whole application and want to create class, that would open in every window, doesnt matter if there is datagrid or no? I was thinking most like about public-avaliable method, which I can run from any place in app ;)

Comment: A contractor that works on a project I am working on thought similarly to your line of thinking. The result was a Singleton Progress Bar.
Now, that progress bar took up the UI thread, so anytime anything was loading the user couldn't do anything, not even move the window out of the way.
It would also crash randomly because of a race condition between different loaders.

Now, my point is this. Use the UI thread only when strictly necessary to avoid the UI locking. Loading notification should be contextual, if you load grid a and b, I want to use grid a as soon as it loads, not after b loads.

Comment: Try "adorning" the grid in question whilst data is loading.

Comment: Well, first of all i want to try Blachshma answer, but cant still update progressBar value (is it progressBar.Value++; for example?) Not really sure where (in loop or something) should i update it.. Maybe you'll be right - well, i have lot of windows, but need that only in several places, where is many items to load, so we'll see ;)

Comment: Please refer to the other answer's comments.
Also, you should not be using a loop, but instead use a Timer. Again this is because a loop will not give back control of the UI thread to actually do the redraw.